# Reading android debug data from raspberry

Tags: raspbian, android, debug

Is there any way to read data from android device connected in debug mode?
I want to read the same data, that shows in Eclipse's LogCat.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you need `adb` command. You should be able to use exactly the same way as on normal desktop Linux. The only thing that may be needed is a `udev` rule that may be created like this (note that `idVendor` may be different for your device):

```
sudo 'echo SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"' >  /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

Now, if you connect your device to the system, you should be able to run:

```
adb logcat -v time
```

The only problem is getting `adb` command working on ARM. And unfortunately this is not that trivial. You can read about how to do this (and download a binary that should work) [on XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1924492).